# Losing weight and getting fit whilst holding down a desk job

Tags: weight-loss

I'm a software engineer and spend pretty much all day everyday in front of my computer coding. 3 months ago I realised that my sedantary job had also become a sedantary lifestyle that made me sad to think that 15 years ago I was heavily into all sort of sports specifically hockey (field) and Badminton being my favourites.

I also have an auto-immune disease called Ankylosing Spondylitis that over the years has calcified the ligaments in my spine giving me very little flexibility and some moderate persistent pain when the calcified ligaments are put under any strain.

I'm sure that the second part above contributed to me giving up on sports and excersize back in the mid 2000's. I realise now that it was a huge mistake to give up on my health and fitness with a convenient excuse.

3 months ago I decided that enough was enough, I was horrified to realise I weighed close to 280lbs and decided to do something about it. I was on holiday with my wife and as the hotel had a fantastic swimming pool and gym I started to use them daily as well as doing the unthinkable whilst on holiday: eating healthily.

3 months on and I'm quite proud with my achievement to date, I've lost nearly 20lbs of weight and am regularly going to the gym and swimming a lot. I've noticed that my back is giving me much less grief as well which is very welcome.

However, I have recently started work with a new client and have realised just how sedentary I am during the day and I'm mindful that I need to move a lot more but I just can't seem to find a way to balance my work with movement and getting some good active calorie burn going during the day.

I'm recording it all on my iPhone with an Apple Watch and am definitely enjoying the game element to closing my rings (currently 820kc / day, 45mins Excersize and 12 hours stand). This is actually the reason I am asking, I have managed to close the rings every day for 2 months now and I'm about to have my first day where I won't be able to achieve my daily goal.

Am I being overy hard on myself for not achieving my goal for one day? I fear that it will be a heavy demotivation for me and that I will just revert slowly back to my old ways.

I'd be really interested to hear from anyone that has overcome one or any of these problems with a desk job and what I can maybe do to overcome my problems I've outlined. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly relevant article from Barbell Medicine: [Training with a "Spondy" Part I](https://www.barbellmedicine.com/blog/spondypartone/) and [Part II](https://www.barbellmedicine.com/blog/training-with-a-spondy-part-ii-returning-to-activity/).

Comment: Semi relevant and an interesting read, thanks @ThomasMarkov